# Insert multiple rows with given values and values from related table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a large insert query like this:

```
INSERT INTO video_tags
  (vid_id, tag_id)
VALUES
  (1,7),
  (2,46),
  (2,52) Etc. Etc.
```

However I don't have the tag_ids to insert, only the tag string. Therefore I need to lookup the tag id as I am inserting them. The tags are stored in a lookup table with two columns:

```
+-----+---------+
| id  | int     |
| tag | varchar |
+-----+---------+
```

I want to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO video_tags
  (vid_id, tag_id)
VALUES
  (1, SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tag = 'banana'),
  (2, SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tag = 'tree')
  (2, SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tag = 'chimps')
```

...but this doesn't work and anyway looks cumbersome and inefficient.

I have also seen this done:

```
INSERT INTO video_tags
  (vid_id, tag_id)
VALUES
  SELECT '1', id FROM tags WHERE tag = 'banana')
```

...but I can't get this to work with multiple selects.

Comment: How about making a table that has your `vid_id`s and tag strings, then doing something like `insert into...from (select vid_id,tag_id`

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding you, I have such a table. It's the one I'm trying to insert values into!

Comment: The one you are inserting into doesn't have `vid_id`s and tag strings. It has `vid_id`s and `tag_id`s.

Comment: Ah, I get you. Seems to go against the idea of keeping the data normalised though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query could go something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE rawdata
    (`vid_id` int, `tag_name` varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO rawdata
    (`vid_id`, `tag_name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'banana'),
    (2, 'tree'),
    (2, 'chimps')
;

INSERT INTO video_tags
SELECT rawdata.vid_id, tag.id FROM
rawdata
LEFT JOIN tag ON tag.tag = rawdata.tag_name
;

DROP TABLE rawdata
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89171/2

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now. That makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ::

```
INSERT INTO video_tags
  (vid_id, tag_id)
VALUES
  (1, (SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tag = 'banana')),
  (2, (SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tag = 'tree')),
  (2, SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tag = 'chimps'));
```

Comment: Hmm. This does work but it takes 0.1s for just 5 entries. If I try my whole query I get an out of resources error. There must be a more efficient way of doing it...?